# Is there a way to know if a user changes the Default "Activity Privacy" for your FB app

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-apps

While it is up to the user as to what they change their default activity privacy (public, friends, only me, custom, etc) I would like to know if there is a way to know if a user changed this from the default - or even better what they changed it to.

My end goal is to see how many users change this, and also how their change affects the click through rate on things my app posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) has two tables for privacy related issues:

1. The [privacy table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/)
2. The [privacy_setting table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/)

Sounds like you're looking for the 2nd table, you can do something like the example there:

```
SELECT name, value, description, allow, deny, networks, friends
FROM privacy_setting
WHERE name = 'default_stream_privacy'
```